# what is the probability of 'heads' coming up?

Tags: python, probability

I have a code for coin flip or "Heads or Tails" but I want to calculate the probability of 5 heads being ejected in a row but I don't know how to do that..

```py
import random

flips = 1
heads = 0
tails= 0

while flips <= 100:
    coin = random.randint(1,2)
    flips +=1
    if coin == 1:
        print("Heads")
        heads += 1
    elif coin == 2:
        print("tails")
        tails += 1

print("You got " + str(heads) +  " heads and " + str(tails) + " tails!")
raw_input("Exit")
```

Comment: I think you're on the wrong forum for that question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, if you want to calculate the probability of 5 heads in a row, how many trials are you referring to?

Comment: The probability of "heads" is 1/2. The probability of two "heads" (independent events) is (1/2)*(1/2) or (1/2)^2. So five heads...

Comment: I don't know how to write a program to calculate it..

Comment: Do you want the *actual mathematical probability* (which is (1/2)^5 as Jonathon mentions)? Or do you want to simulate n-events and get the probability from those events (which will NOT be *equal* to the mathematical probability, but it will be close)

Comment: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/Probability.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

There are several definitions of `P(E)`, the probability that event `E` will occur. But for your simulation we have to go with one based on performing trials and looking at outcomes.

The experiment consists of throwing 5 coins in a row and observing if 5 heads come up in a row. Of course, once you get a tails, there is no point in completing the 5 coin tosses (take note of that). Each time you do these up-to-5 coin tosses and observe whether or not heads came up all 5 times is a *trial*. If you perform `N` trials and you observe heads came up 5 times in a row `M` out of the `N` times, then as the number of trials `N` approaches infinity, `P(5 head tosses) = M/N`.

Of course, you will not be able to do an infinite number of trials, but you should try different values of large N and see what results you get.

So the outer loop is performed `N` times. These are the trials. The inner loop is performed 1 to 5 times (until you get a tails). If you are successful in throwing 5 successful heads, you would increment `M`, which is initially 0. Your final probability is `M/N`.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of seems like a homework problem, so I'm going to try to talk through the method, rather than give the answer:

Finding probability of flipping one coin as 'heads': 
You need to find the chance of your 1 outcome divided by the total number of outcomes

```
probability = number_of_chances_heads / total_number_of_outcomes
```

Finding probability of flipping a coin as 'heads' 5x in a row: 
You need to multiply the original probability by itself the number of times you want the outcome.

```
fivex_probability = probability ** number_of_times_you_want_outcome
```

Answer (score 0):

Probability of getting heads once is 0.5, and getting it 5 times in a row is 0.5^5 = 0.03125

If you wanted to do this in python you could just do that operation, but it looks like what you're trying to do is to approximate the results by doing a simulation AKA using a montecarlo approach. You were actually almost there :)

```
import random 

 flips = 1 
 heads = 0 
 tails= 0 

 num_tests = 1000 
 passed_tests = 0 


 for flips in range(num_tests):
     heads, tails = 0, 0 
     for subflip in range(5):
         coin == random.randint(1,2) 
         if coin = 1:
             print("Heads") 
             heads += 1 
         elif coin == 2:
             print("tails") 
             tails += 1 

     if heads == 5:
         print("had 5 heads in a row!") 
         passed_tests+=1 

 print("Got 5 heads in a row {} times {:.2%} of the time".format(passed_tests, passed_tests/float(num_tests)))
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but it shouldn't be the OP's homework assignment.